# Why flock(2) on one file descriptor is interfered by another in the same process

Tags: linux, file, flock

1、In mannual:https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html,There are tips as follows:

(1). Locks created by flock() are associated with an open file description (see
open(2));

(2). If a process uses open(2) (or similar) to obtain more than one file descriptor
for the same file, these file descriptors are treated independently by flock(). An attempt to lock the file using one of these file descriptors may be denied by a lock that the calling process has already placed via another file descriptor.

2、In my code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd1 = open("tfile.txt", O_RDWR);
    int fd2 = open("tfile.txt", O_RDWR);
    printf("fd1: %d, fd2: %d\n", fd1, fd2);
    flock(fd1, LOCK_EX);
    printf("Lock fd1....\n");
    flock(fd2, LOCK_UN);
    printf("Unlock fd2....\n");
    flock(fd2, LOCK_EX);
    errExit("Lock fd2...");

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
[apple@localhost filelock]$ ./d_flock 
fd1: 3, fd2: 4
Lock fd1....
Unlock fd2....
```

3、My question is:

I. As fd1 and fd2 have different open file description,Why "flock(fd2, LOCK_EX)" will be blocked?

II. Why "flock(fd2, LOCK_UN)" won't unlock the file lock on fd1?

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR: Don't do what the docs say you should not do.

> As fd1 and fd2 have different open file description,Why "flock(fd2, LOCK_EX)" will be blocked?

Because your lock is associated with the file descriptor and, as you say yourself, you have two of them (file descriptors, not locks).
You have two file descriptors for the same file, **your** lock on `fd1` is *not* associated with the file name, but with `fd1` - but that the file is locked is very much associated with the file itself.  So when you try to block the same file with a different file descriptor, the fact that *you* own the lock associated with `fd1` is of no consequence when trying to lock the same file with a second file descriptor `fd2`, resulting in a blocking system call - that is an error on you part, in direct contradiction to the documentation you cited.

> Why "flock(fd2, LOCK_UN)" won't unlock the file lock on fd1?

For the same reason as your first question: There is no lock associated with `fd2`, so the call is basically a no-op - the system doesn't care that you have the same file open twice.  C is a low level language, the book-keeping necessary to detect all possible combinations of file names, file descriptors open etc. would be too costly in most cases.